# Integrating $e^{-(t|k|^\alpha+ixk)} $ with respect to $k$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Is there any way to calculate below integral ?: 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{ \infty}
\exp\left(-t\left\vert\, k\,\right\vert^{\alpha} - \,\mathrm{i}kx\right)
\,\mathrm{d}k\qquad\mbox{where}\quad 0 < \alpha < 2
$$

Comment: @Dr.MV It was a sign missing in the integral. Thank you for your comment

Comment: This looks like the Fourier transform of $e^{-k^\alpha}$

Comment: It is exactly that. @polfosol

Comment: This seems to be closely related to a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution).

Comment: In case of alpha = 2, that is right. @Masacroso

Comment: just absolute value is important. Look at question @GyuEunLee

Comment: It seems this has a closed form only for $\alpha\in\{0,1,2\}$. I seriously doubt that there could be a closed form for other values.

Comment: I agree with the comment of @polfosol . To back this up a bit we can consider the special case $x=0$ for which the integrand simplifies. Even in this case we would need the [incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) to evaluate the integral. This is a fairly complicated non-elementary function. If you instead want an approximation then that might be a more tractable problem.

Comment: What are approximation that you could solve the problem with? @Winther

Comment: I think $$e^{-|k|^\alpha}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}|k|^{n\alpha}$$ would be a good start...

Comment: $\alpha=1/2$ can also be given in closed form

Comment: I think this is going to give a hypergeometric function in general.